# Problem when running query with MINUS filter in jena

Tags: sparql, jena

I want to add the MINUS filter in a query but when I add it the query simply does not execute, but when I remove the MINUS filter the query executes normally.

This is the code when I use MINUS:

```
Query sparql = QueryFactory.create("PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>\r\n" + 
                "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\r\n" + 
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                "SELECT ?s ?c ?p ?o FROM <http://147.27.60.65/sensorOntology> WHERE {?s rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual.\r\n" + 
                "?p rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty.\r\n" + 
                "?c rdf:type owl:Class.\r\n" + 
                "?s rdf:type ?c.\r\n" +
                "?s ?p ?o\r\n" + 
                "MINUS {?s rdf:type owl:Thing}\r\n" + 
                "}");
QueryExecution vqe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(sparql, inf);
```

This is the code that executes correctly when I do not use MINUS:

```
Query sparql = QueryFactory.create("PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>\r\n" + 
                "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\r\n" + 
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                "SELECT ?s ?c ?p ?o FROM <http://147.27.60.65/sensorOntology> WHERE {?s rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual.\r\n" + 
                "?p rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty.\r\n" + 
                "?c rdf:type owl:Class.\r\n" + 
                "?s rdf:type ?c.\r\n" +
                "?s ?p ?o}");
         QueryExecution vqe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(sparql, inf);
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax? Is it perhaps that I query a `InfModel` type ?

Comment: Which `InfModel` resp. reasoner do you use? If you use some OWL profile or even Pellet then by inference every individual belongs to `owl:Thing` which in fact means you're subtracting all possible individuals from the solution bindings of the left side of `MINUS`

Comment: I am using Pellet. The reason I am asking this is because I dont want to get the same individual many times. Without the minus I get the same Individual as type owl:Thing AND as type the corresponding class it is supposed to be. I dont want to have the owl:Thing as a result in my query but I do want to get the individual with its correct class type.

Comment: the correct way is to use a simple filter on the solutions then: `filter(?c != owl:Thing)` - that's all you need to avoid "rows" with the type `owl:Thing` in the resultset

Comment: just to clarify, you'll always get multiple rows for an individual if it a) belongs to multiple classes or b) is used with multiple properties. With your query you'' even get the combinations of them as neither class nor property are directly related. For example, if you have `:s rdf:type A1 . :s rdf:type A2 .` and `:s :p1 :o1 . :s :p2 :o2 .` you'll get rows for `:s :A1 :p1 :o1`| `:s :A2 :p1 :o1` | `:s :A1 :p2 :o1` | `:s :A2 :p2 :o1` | - that's how SPARQL works! I don't think this result is useful but nobody knows what you really want as result ...

Comment: Why not filter solutions where ?c is owl:Thing...? e.g. `FILTER (?c != owl:Thing)` The class owl:NamedIndividual is a sub-class of owl:Thing so `MINUS` as written by you, will fileter out all solutions

Comment: I have the following: ```:s rdf:type A1 . :s rdf:type A2 ``` the the reasoner infers that ```:s tdf:type owl:Thing```. That is happening for all individuals. Is there a way to query all individuals and their types along with their object properties without returning  ```:s tdf:type owl:Thing``` and the rows that come with it? I do want to get the row ```:s :A1 :p1 :o1``` but only two times(for A1 and A2, not owl:Thing).

Comment: Using ```FILTER (?c != owl:Thing)``` did the trick. Thanks!!